# Get header from HttpResponse in Android

Tags: java, android, http, http-headers

Is there a way to get the value of a specific header using the `HttpResponse` object returned by the `HttpClient` `execute()` method in Android?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are several ways to get specific headers. [HttpResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) inherits from [HttpMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html), which provides the following header retrieval methods:

- [`Header getFirstHeader(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#getFirstHeader%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`Header[] getHeaders(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`Header  getLastHeader(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#getLastHeader%28java.lang.String%29)

In your case, **you probably want `getFirstHeader(String)`**. Headers can contain multiple values, hence the `Header[]` array return from `getHeaders()`; if you only expect there to be a single header, `getFirstHeader(String)` should suffice.

Comment: These functions all return `Header` not `String`

Comment: Looks like the API's changed since this answer was written. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/Header.html has a `GetValue()`.

Comment: @RobHruska Indeed. Use `httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location")` now

Answer (score 7):

I always use this code

Initially, I do so

```
 Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
```

Next, I'm using a simple method converts in hashmap

```
 private HashMap<String, String> convertHeadersToHashMap(Header[] headers) {
    HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>(headers.length);
    for (Header header : headers) {
        result.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I can get any value

Maybe someone can help
Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `HttpResponse.getHeaders()` method?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to get a specific header without iterating over all of them.

Answer (score 2):

try the below method :-

```
URL obj = new URL("http://mkyong.com");
    URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
    Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();

    System.out.println("Printing Response Header...\n");

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                           + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("\nGet Response Header By Key ...\n");
    String server = conn.getHeaderField("Server");

    if (server == null) {
        System.out.println("Key 'Server' is not found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Server - " + server);
    }

    System.out.println("\n Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Please try `HttpResponse.getAllHeaders()` for printing headers and for printing cookie in Headers.

```
response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")
```

Comment: what is the next step to get redirected URL ?