# HttpGet JSONArray android Progressbar

Tags: java, php, android, json, http

I'm trying to get a horizontal progressbardialog for the json array I download from the internet.
Here is my current code

```
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Date... arg0) {
  try {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String result = null;

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 30000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),
            30000);

    String getter = arg0[0].getDate();

    URI website = new URI("http://10.0.2.2/bmorg/getEvent?day=" + getter);

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(website);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
            .getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String l = "";
    String nl = System.getProperty("line.seperator");
    while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(l + nl);
    }

    in.close();
    result = sb.toString();

    return new JSONArray(result);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    _worked = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}
```

This works fine, but what I want is a download status. I don't know how to get the size from my Http request and the downloaded bytes to put this to the progressbar onChange method.

Answer (score 0):

Update your progress here:

```
while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(l + nl);
    }
```

You can use `AsyncTask.publishProgress` and `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate` methods for it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [size of the http response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424611/get-header-from-httpresponse-in-android) to [set the progress bar max](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setMax%28int%29) value, and then [update the progress bar progress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#incrementProgressBy%28int%29) in the `while` loop.

Comment: The server may not give the Content-Length, in which case you are doomed to use the indeterminate style.